# Hide child and parent repeater when child repeater is empty

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a question regarding repeaters in ASP.net

I have 2 repeaters nested.
I would like to hide both the parent and the child repeater whenever the child repeater holds no items.
Each parent with their child items are giving unique classes like 'class="childlist_1"'.

ascx file:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="ParentRepeater" runat="server">
<ItemTemplate>
    <ul class="Mainlist">
       <li>
        <h3 class="selected"><a href="#">List 1</a></h3>
        <ul id="DomainList" class="child-items" runat="server">
            <asp:Repeater ID="ChildRepeater" runat="server">
                <ItemTemplate><li><a href="#">Link to child item</a></li></ItemTemplate>
            </asp:Repeater>
        </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

What is the best solution for this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this in [ItemDataBound](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.repeater.itemdatabound%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) event

```
protected void ParentRepeater_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item)
    {
        // code that binds ChildRepeater
        .....

        // check if ChildRepeater has no items
        if (((Repeater)e.Item.FindControl("ChildRepeater")).Items.Count == 0)
        {
            e.Item.Visible = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do I use this in the ItemDataBound event?

Comment: See my edited answer if you want to do this in ItemDataBound event.

Answer (score 0):

If like me you like to use a method to bind the child repeater (i.e. `DataSource='<%# GetChildDatasource(Eval("parentID").ToString()) %>'`), this won't work as the datasource is binded after the parent's itemdatabound method is triggered.

The workaround is to use the PreRender method on the child repeater :

```
protected void ChildRpt_PreRender(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //hide if empty
    Repeater rpt = (Repeater)sender;
    rpt.Visible = rpt.Items.Count > 0;

}
```