# How can I hide empty nested repeaters?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, webforms

In an asp.net page, I have nested repeaters to show up to four levels of my sitemap.

**The question:** *How can I tell the nested repeaters not to show a node if the node has no children?*  More specifically, when a nested repeater has no children, it renders as a pair of `<ul></ul>`  tags -- that's what I need to hide from the rendered list.

**What works:** The HTML and script presented here renders the web.sitemap correctly as a clean unordered list, only with empty UL tags where a node has no children.

**What I have tried (unsuccesfully) so far:**

- I have looked into jQuery. Although I found the correct jQuery command to remove empty `<ul>` pairs, the webresource makes absolutely sure to overwrite jQuery commands. (Which also makes it impossible for me to use jQuery to remove classes that litter a rendered asp:menu). In other words, I have not yet found a way for jQuery to clean up something produced by an asp.net control.
- I found forum posts, but they all seem to have repeated the same two-level depth repeater without any removal of childless nodes.
- I double-checked my web.sitemap file and made sure I had nothing in the source that would contribute to this. No issues there at the source.

Looking around, I found a very promising post here: [Hide child and parent repeater when child repeater is empty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21530842/hide-child-and-parent-repeater-when-child-repeater-is-empty).  Adapting it to VB.NET and adding a null detection if-then statement, I have:

```
Protected Sub HideIfEmpty(sender As Object, e As RepeaterItemEventArgs) Handles Repeater0.ItemDataBound
    If e.Item.ItemType = ListItemType.Item Then
        If e.Item.FindControl("Repeater4") IsNot Nothing Then

            If (DirectCast(e.Item.FindControl("Repeater3"), Repeater).Items.Count = 0) Then
                e.Item.Visible = False
            End If

        End If

    End If
End Sub
```

Based on a comment, I also tried a PreRender sub. It presented a sitemap list with the same empty UL tags. Use of breakpoints did not identify why it was not working as desired.

**This is the aspx code:**

```
<asp:SiteMapDataSource ID="siteMapDataSource1" runat="server" ShowStartingNode="false" />
<asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="Repeater0" DataSourceID="SiteMapDataSource1">
    <HeaderTemplate>
        <ul>
            <li>
                <asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink4" runat="server" NavigateUrl="~/index.aspx">Homepage</asp:HyperLink>
            </li>
    </HeaderTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <li>
            <asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink1" runat="server" NavigateUrl='<%# Eval("Url") %>'><%# Eval("Title") %></asp:HyperLink>
            <asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server" DataSource='<%# DirectCast(Container.DataItem, SiteMapNode).ChildNodes%>'>
                <HeaderTemplate>
                    <ul>
                </HeaderTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <li>
                        <asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink2" runat="server" NavigateUrl='<%# Eval("Url") %>'><%# Eval("Title") %></asp:HyperLink>
                        <asp:Repeater ID="Repeater2" runat="server" DataSource='<%# DirectCast(Container.DataItem, SiteMapNode).ChildNodes%>'>
                            <HeaderTemplate>
                                <ul>
                            </HeaderTemplate>
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <li>
                                    <asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink3" runat="server" NavigateUrl='<%# Eval("Url") %>'><%# Eval("Title") %></asp:HyperLink>
                                    <asp:Repeater ID="Repeater3" runat="server" DataSource='<%# DirectCast(Container.DataItem, SiteMapNode).ChildNodes%>' OnPreRender="HideIfEmpty">
                                        <HeaderTemplate>
                                            <ul>
                                        </HeaderTemplate>
                                        <ItemTemplate>
                                            <li>
                                                <asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink3" runat="server" NavigateUrl='<%# Eval("Url") %>'><%# Eval("Title") %></asp:HyperLink>
                                            </li>
                                        </ItemTemplate>
                                        <FooterTemplate>
                                            </ul>
                                        </FooterTemplate>
                                    </asp:Repeater>
                                </li>
                            </ItemTemplate>
                            <FooterTemplate>
                                </ul>
                            </FooterTemplate>
                        </asp:Repeater>
                    </li>
                </ItemTemplate>
                <FooterTemplate>
                    </ul>
                </FooterTemplate>
            </asp:Repeater>
        </li>
    </ItemTemplate>
    <FooterTemplate></ul></FooterTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

**This is the rendered HTML:**

```
<ul id="menu_Main" class="sm sm-blue">
<li>
    <a id="Repeater0_HyperLink4" href="index.aspx">Homepage</a>
</li>

<li>
    <a id="Repeater0_HyperLink1_0">Data Manager Documents</a>

    <ul>

        <li>
            <a id="Repeater0_Repeater1_0_HyperLink2_0" href="/Data_Manager/Skill_Journal.aspx">Skill Journal</a>

            <ul>
            </ul>

        </li>

        <li>
            <a id="Repeater0_Repeater1_0_HyperLink2_1">Test Pages</a>

            <ul>

                <li>
                    <a id="Repeater0_Repeater1_0_Repeater2_1_HyperLink3_0" href="/Data_Manager/xslt_test.aspx">XSLT Test</a>

                    <ul>
                    </ul>

                </li>

            </ul>

        </li>

    </ul>

</li>

<li>
    <a id="Repeater0_HyperLink1_1">Incident Report</a>

    <ul>

        <li>
            <a id="Repeater0_Repeater1_1_HyperLink2_0" href="http://wales:4885/IncidentReport/IncidentReport.aspx">Add/Edit/View</a>

            <ul>
            </ul>

        </li>

        <li>
            <a id="Repeater0_Repeater1_1_HyperLink2_1" href="http://wales:4885/IncidentReport/V1_History.aspx">Archive</a>

            <ul>
            </ul>

        </li>

    </ul>

</li>

<li>
    <a id="Repeater0_HyperLink1_2" href="/Ordering_Database/Ordering_Database.aspx">Ordering Database</a>

    <ul>

        <li>
            <a id="Repeater0_Repeater1_2_HyperLink2_0" href="/Ordering_Database/Reports.aspx">Reports</a>

            <ul>
            </ul>

        </li>

        <li>
            <a id="Repeater0_Repeater1_2_HyperLink2_1" href="/Ordering_Database/Stats.aspx">Stats</a>

            <ul>
            </ul>

        </li>

        <li>
            <a id="Repeater0_Repeater1_2_HyperLink2_2" href="/Ordering_Database/View_Items.aspx">View Items</a>

            <ul>
            </ul>

        </li>

        <li>
            <a id="Repeater0_Repeater1_2_HyperLink2_3" href="/Ordering_Database/Manage_Items.aspx">Manage Items</a>

            <ul>
            </ul>

        </li>
        <li>
            <a id="Repeater0_Repeater1_2_HyperLink2_4">Utility</a>
            <ul>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

In summary, the sitemap that is rendered into a nested unordered list is correct, but still produces empty UL tags that should be removed on the server side.

Comment: Is something still wrong at this point after your latest update?

Comment: Yes. I'm a few minutes from posting my next update. This one is really weird: when I rebuild the solution & look at the rendered html page, the empty UL tags are there. When I apply a jQuery command, it has the appearance of removing the tags so that my CSS menu works correctly, when I right click to view source, the empty UL tags are still there.

Comment: I worked out an answer from a different angle. It's a very simple sub. Now If I could simplify the nested repeaters in the body, that would be an even stronger win.

Comment: Great - glad you were able to figure something out!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this system, this is what worked for me as true server side answer.

In the script:

```
<script>
Private Sub Hide_The_Orphans(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As RepeaterItemEventArgs)
    Dim rpt As Repeater = CType(sender, Repeater)

    If rpt IsNot Nothing Then
        If rpt.Items.Count = 0 Then
            rpt.Visible = False
        Else
            rpt.Visible = True
        End If
    End If
End Sub
</script>
```

In the body (I also changed changed the asp:hyperlink tags to `<a>` tags to clean up all those hyperlink IDs in the rendered HTML):

```
<nav>
                <asp:SiteMapDataSource ID="siteMapDataSource1" runat="server" ShowStartingNode="false" />
                <asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="Repeater0" DataSourceID="SiteMapDataSource1">
                    <HeaderTemplate>
                        <ul id="menu_Main" class="sm sm-blue">
                            <li>
                                <a href='<%# Page.ResolveClientUrl("~/index.aspx")%>'>Homepage</a>
                            </li>
                    </HeaderTemplate>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <li>
                            <a href='<%# Eval("Url") %>'><%# Eval("Title") %></a>
                            <asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server" DataSource='<%# DirectCast(Container.DataItem, SiteMapNode).ChildNodes%>' OnItemDataBound="Hide_The_Orphans">
                                <HeaderTemplate>
                                    <ul>
                                </HeaderTemplate>
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <li>
                                        <a href='<%# Eval("Url") %>'><%# Eval("Title") %></a>
                                        <asp:Repeater ID="Repeater2" runat="server" DataSource='<%# DirectCast(Container.DataItem, SiteMapNode).ChildNodes%>' OnItemDataBound="Hide_The_Orphans">
                                            <HeaderTemplate>
                                                <ul>
                                            </HeaderTemplate>
                                            <ItemTemplate>
                                                <li>
                                                    <a href='<%# Eval("Url") %>'><%# Eval("Title") %></a>
                                                    <asp:Repeater ID="Repeater3" runat="server" DataSource='<%# DirectCast(Container.DataItem, SiteMapNode).ChildNodes%>' OnItemDataBound="Hide_The_Orphans">
                                                        <HeaderTemplate>
                                                            <ul>
                                                        </HeaderTemplate>
                                                        <ItemTemplate>
                                                            <li>
                                                                <a href='<%# Eval("Url") %>'><%# Eval("Title") %></a>
                                                            </li>
                                                        </ItemTemplate>
                                                        <FooterTemplate>
                                                            </ul>
                                                        </FooterTemplate>
                                                    </asp:Repeater>
                                                </li>
                                            </ItemTemplate>
                                            <FooterTemplate>
                                                </ul>
                                            </FooterTemplate>
                                        </asp:Repeater>
                                    </li>
                                </ItemTemplate>
                                <FooterTemplate>
                                    </ul>
                                </FooterTemplate>
                            </asp:Repeater>
                        </li>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                    <FooterTemplate></ul></FooterTemplate>
                </asp:Repeater>
            </nav>
```

And to prove to myself it's a true server side solution, this is from "view source code."

```
                        <ul id="menu_Main" class="sm sm-blue">
                            <li>
                                <a href='index.aspx'>Homepage</a>
                            </li>

                        <li>
                            <a href=''>Data Manager Documents</a>

                                    <ul>

                                    <li>
                                        <a href='/Data_Manager/Skill_Journal.aspx'>Skill Journal</a>

                                    </li>

                                    <li>
                                        <a href=''>Test Pages</a>

                                                <ul>

                                                <li>
                                                    <a href='/Data_Manager/.aspx'>Sitemap test</a>

                                                </li>

                                                <li>
                                                    <a href='/Data_Manager/xslt_test.aspx'>XSLT Test</a>

                                                </li>

                                                </ul>

                                    </li>

                                    </ul>

                        </li>

                        etc....
```

The places were you see empty href tags is because those specific nodes are more like folder containers, so that's design and not bug.

Another plus for this approach is that there is only one sub that can get used by any of the repeaters, rather than having to use a chained approach as I earlier attempted.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're pretty much there. One of your issues is that you are trying to find Repeater3 within Repeater0, when it is actually in Repeater2. You need to properly go down the line of Repeaters, finding the correct child ID. Here is an example using the `OnPreRender` event, though you could still get it working for `OnItemDataBound` using similar logic.

```
<asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="Repeater0" DataSourceID="SiteMapDataSource1" OnPreRender="Repeater0_PreRender">
```

Within this event, dig through each child repeater. If the child repeater has no items, hide the entire repeater. You should be able to get an idea from this code here. You would probably be better off recursively looping the child Repeaters, however.

```
Protected Sub Repeater0_PreRender(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)

    Dim repeater0 As Repeater = sender
    If repeater0.Items.Count = 0 Then
        repeater0.Visible = False
    Else
        For Each repeater0Item As RepeaterItem In repeater0.Items
            If repeater0Item.ItemType = ListItemType.Item Then
                Dim repeater1 As Repeater = repeater0Item.FindControl("Repeater1")
                If repeater1.Items.Count = 0 Then
                    repeater1.Visible = False
                Else
                    For Each repeater1Item As RepeaterItem In repeater1.Items
                        If repeater1Item.ItemType = ListItemType.Item Then
                            Dim repeater2 As Repeater = repeater1Item.FindControl("Repeater2")
                            If repeater2.Items.Count = 0 Then
                                repeater2.Visible = False
                            Else
                                // so on and so forth
                            End If
                        End If
                    Next
                End If
            End If
        Next
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks. I'm testing that codeblock out now. I'm trying to figure out what "rpt" is in "For Each repeater1Item As RepeaterItem In rpt.Items".  Did you mean to type something else?

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo. Should be fixed now. Thanks for catching that.

Comment: I gave it two tries and I'm still seeing empty <ul> tags. No server errors, but no change in rendered HTML either :( You mentioned recursive. I like the concept, but have not been able to find examples for nested repeaters to date. Maybe a literal search for "sitemap recurse nested repeaters" is not the correct search term?

Comment: Hmm...seemed to work for me and my attempts. Have you set in breakpoints to make sure it's marking things as hidden when it should?

Comment: I've been using using the "label1.text" approach since we can't do vb alerts.  Level 2 is acting a little funny....  Rechecking code for typos.

Comment: Setting `label.text` isn't going to provide any sort of useful debugging. It will display the result of the last row, which in your case is a footer because you have a `<FooterTemplate>`. Since `ListItemType.Item <> ListItemType.Footer`, you fall to the else every time. Use breakpoints instead.

Comment: I don't know what your setup looks like, but you *can* put breakpoints in and debug master pages. If there is no possible way however, try using `Response.Write` to write messages to your screen. This way you won't have messages overwriting other messages.

Comment: I can add breakpoints now.  I'll start looking into the step-by-step process.